# cannot target specific cell in a sheet (google app script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a script that takes the selected option in column F and updates a different sheet with the selected value. The first sheet is set up like this

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Names of other sheets | Month | Day | Weekday | Options |

[image]

The other sheets are set to start on the 16th of the month and finish on the 15th of the following month. So the sheet labeled (2023/01) has dates starting from row 7. The dates are in column A and the value to be updated is in column D.

[image]

**The problem**

In the script, the dates are all offset by one. So if you select 23/01/16 it actually matches 23/01/17. This doesn't seem to be a problem except when the 15th of every month is selected. Since the sheets end on the 15th and the dates are offset it matches the 16th but the 16th does not exist on the sheet so the cell is not updated.

**MY solution**

To fix this issue I created a condition to check if the selected date includes '/16' then run some code. I then created a variable to get the previous sheet and got the last row and set the value that way. I used toast() to check if the values I am selecting are correct and they seem to be. The sheet name is correct and the last row is correct but I am not actually seeing the cell being updated. I am not sure what I am doing wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* 休日入力イベント
--------------------------------------*/
function changeHoliday(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //アクティブなシート
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  var atvc = sheet.getActiveCell(); //アクティブセル

  //休日シートの休日を変更した時だけ
  if(sheetName=='休日' || sheetName && atvc.getColumn() == 6){
    var flag = atvc.getValue(); //休日かどうか
    var targetSheetName = String(atvc.offset(1, -4).getValue()); //対応するシート名

    //Get previous sheet name
    var prevSheetName = String(atvc.offset(-1,-4).getValue());


    var targetDate = Utilities.formatDate(atvc.offset(1, -5).getValue(),"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd"); //対応する日付
    // var targetDateEndofSheet = Utilities.formatDate(atvc.offset(0, -5).getValue(),"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd"); 
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    var values = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues();
    // 取得したデータから一致する日付を探す
    //original i=7


    for (var i=7; i<lastRow; i++){
      var d =  Utilities.formatDate(values[i][0],"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd");

      //My if statement
      if(targetDate.includes("/16")) {

        var targetS = ss.getSheetByName(prevSheetName); //get the pervious sheet
        var lastR = targetS.getLastRow(); //get the last row of the previous sheet

        //check the values
        ss.toast( "prev sheet name " + prevSheetName +"last r: " + lastR + "flag" + flag + "td " + targetDate)
        //select the cell 4 of the last row
        var r = prevSheetName.getRange(lastR,4);

         r.setValue(flag); //set the select value
      }
      if(d == targetDate){
       
        var range = targetSheet.getRange(i,4);

        // データ追加
        range.setValue(flag);
      }
    }
  }
  //一度に1つの日付を入力してください
 


}


/* 休日の保護の解除
--------------------------------------*/
function protectionRemove_(targetDate){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    // 説明文が一致したら削除
    if (protection.getDescription() == targetDate) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

**I was able to solve it with some of the suggestions made in the comments**

I added this to my code

```
       if(d.includes("/16") && targetDate.includes("/16")) {
        var prevSheetName = String(atvc.offset(-1, -4).getValue()); //get target page
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(prevSheetName); 
        var lr= targetSheet.getLastRow(); //select the last of the target page
         var r = targetSheet.getRange(lr,4); //set the range
         r.setValue(flag);
       }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What are 2 images? What is the most left column of the sheet image of the bottom one? In your images are the sample input situations? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situations you expect? From `if you select 23/01/16 it actually matches 23/01/17`, in your Spreadsheet, the timezone of the Spreadsheet is the same as the Google Apps Script project? I cannot understand `Since the sheets end on the 15th and the dates are offset it matches the 16th but the 16th does not exist on the sheet so the cell is not updated.`.

Comment: I) What do you want to do? II) Please log `atvc.offset(1, -5).getValue()` and `targetDate`. III) Why do you have to convert `date` into `string`?

Comment: @Tanaike Since I did not write this code originally I am not sure why some things are written the way they are. In the first image, 23/2/16 is the value that is checked in the loop is actually 23/2/17. 
In the second image, you can see the sheet ends on 23/2/15. So if I select 23/02/15  in the first sheet there is no value 23/02/16 on the second sheet. I hope this makes more sense. I am sorry if I did not explain it well.

Comment: @idfurw I tried your solution and it seems to select different dates. For example, if on the first sheet I select 23/01/16 then in the month sheet 23/01/17 is selected. I tried to change the offset of the target date from 1 to 0 but then it gives me unexpected results. It will select two dates.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand `if I select 23/02/15 in the first sheet there is no value 23/02/16 on the second sheet.`. And in your script, how do you run the function `changeHoliday` and `protectionRemove_`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `for (var i=6; i<lastRow; i++){` and `var range = targetSheet.getRange(i + 2,4);`.

Comment: @Tanaike in sheet one if I select 23/02/15  the value that is checked in the code is 23/02/16 . The target second sheet ends on 23/02/15 but since its evaluation is 23/02/16 then there is no cell to write in. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @idfurw Thanks for your reply. This then goes two dates down. Should I be leaving this as `var targetDate = Utilities.formatDate(atvc.offset(1, -5).getValue(),"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd");` as is? this is what is offsetting the date.
Also, I forgot to answer. Since I did not write this code I do not why the date was converted to a string.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your time. I was able to fix it. I'm sorry I could not explain well enough but I appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: @idfurw Thank you for your help. With your suggestions, I was able to fix it by adding this
`if(d.includes("/16") && targetDate.includes("/16")) {
        var prevSheetName = String(atvc.offset(-1, -4).getValue()); //get target page
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(prevSheetName); 
        var lr= targetSheet.getLastRow(); //select the last of the target page
         var r = targetSheet.getRange(lr,4); //set the range
         r.setValue(flag);
       }`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated my question with the code I used to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find my explanation in the comments:

```js
function changeHoliday(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //アクティブなシート
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  var atvc = sheet.getActiveCell(); //アクティブセル

  //休日シートの休日を変更した時だけ
  /* Should be AND OPERATOR */
  if(sheetName=='休日' && sheetName && atvc.getColumn() == 6){
    var flag = atvc.getValue(); //休日かどうか
    /* Should check the value */
    if (flag == '休日') {
      /* Row offset should be 0 */
      var targetSheetName = String(atvc.offset(0, -4).getValue()); //対応するシート名

      //Get previous sheet name
      /* Not needed */
      // var prevSheetName = String(atvc.offset(-1,-4).getValue());

      /* Row offset should be 0 */
      var targetDate = Utilities.formatDate(atvc.offset(0, -5).getValue(),"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd"); //対応する日付
      // var targetDateEndofSheet = Utilities.formatDate(atvc.offset(0, -5).getValue(),"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd"); 
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
      var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
      var values = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues();
      // 取得したデータから一致する日付を探す
      //original i=7

      /* i should starts from 6 */
      for (var i=6; i<lastRow; i++){
        var d =  Utilities.formatDate(values[i][0],"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd");

      //My if statement
      /* Not needed */
      /*
      if(targetDate.includes("/16")) {

        var targetS = ss.getSheetByName(prevSheetName); //get the pervious sheet
        var lastR = targetS.getLastRow(); //get the last row of the previous sheet

        //check the values
        ss.toast( "prev sheet name " + prevSheetName +"last r: " + lastR + "flag" + flag + "td " + targetDate)
        //select the cell 4 of the last row
        var r = prevSheetName.getRange(lastR,4);

         r.setValue(flag); //set the select value
      }
      */
        if(d == targetDate){
       
          /* Row should be i + 1 */
          var range = targetSheet.getRange(i + 1,4);

          // データ追加
          range.setValue(flag);

          /* Better to break */
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //一度に1つの日付を入力してください
 


}
```

To simplify:

```js
function changeHoliday(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  var atvc = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if(sheetName=='休日' && sheetName && atvc.getColumn() == 6){
    var flag = atvc.getValue();
    if (flag == '休日') {
      var targetSheetName = String(atvc.offset(0, -4).getValue());
      var targetDate = Utilities.formatDate(atvc.offset(0, -5).getValue(),"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd"); //対応する日付
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
      var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
      var values = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,1).getValues();

      for (var i=6; i<lastRow; i++){
        var d =  Utilities.formatDate(values[i][0],"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd");
        if(d == targetDate){
          var range = targetSheet.getRange(i + 1,4);
          range.setValue(flag);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my solution worked but this is much cleaner.